# Dplyr to summarize columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset

```
company_category_list Cluster
Biotechnology         1
Software              2
Biotechnology|Search  1
Biotechnology         1
Biotechnology         1
Enterprise Software   3
Software              2
```

I want to get a count of the 1st column grouped by the column Cluster so used the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
CountSummary <-SFBay_2012 %>% 
group_by(Cluster) %>% 
summarise(company_category_list_Count = count_(company_category_list))
```

But getting the following error:

```
Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Can anybody help out? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `count_` not supposed to be `count` ? Or maybe just `n()` ?

Comment: Also, there is a discrepancy between the code you have pasted and the error you have pasted. `group_by_` is not the same as `group_by`

Comment: This is the entire code alongwith the error: CountSummary <-SFBay_2012 %>% 
+     group_by(Cluster) %>% 
+   summarise(company_category_list_Count = count(company_category_list))
Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: `count` will not go along with `summarise`.  Please check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess we need

```
SFBay_2012 %>%
        group_by(Cluster) %>% 
        count(company_category_list)   
#   Cluster company_category_list     n
#    <int>                 <chr> <int>
#1       1         Biotechnology     3
#2       1  Biotechnology|Search     1
#3       2              Software     2
#4       3   Enterprise Software     1
```

Or

```
SFBay_2012 %>% 
      count(Cluster, company_category_list)
#  Cluster company_category_list     n
#    <int>                 <chr> <int>
#1       1         Biotechnology     3
#2       1  Biotechnology|Search     1
#3       2              Software     2
#4       3   Enterprise Software     1
```

Or

```
SFBay_2012 %>%
        group_by(Cluster, company_category_list) %>% 
        tally()
#   Cluster company_category_list     n
#     <int>                 <chr> <int>
#1       1         Biotechnology     3
#2       1  Biotechnology|Search     1
#3       2              Software     2
#4       3   Enterprise Software     1
```

Or

```
SFBay_2012 %>%
     group_by(Cluster, company_category_list) %>%
     summarise(n = n())
```